# What's wrong with this csh file?

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, csh

I don't have any experience writing .sh files. I want to run the pvm2raw utility of [this app](http://code.google.com/p/vvv/downloads/list?q=VIEWER) from the [Volume Library](http://www9.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/External/vollib/).

I get the following error when running build.sh in Ubuntu 10.10.

[image]

build.sh is as follows:

```
# make command
set mmfile=V3Makefile
set make="make -f $mmfile"

set rule=$1
if ($rule == "") set rule="all" // line 16

if ($rule == "deps") then
   if ($HOSTTYPE == "iris4d") $make MAKEDEPEND="CC -M" OPTS="-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DVIEWER_HAVE_DCMTK" TARGET=IRIX depend
   if ($HOSTTYPE == "i386") $make MAKEDEPEND="c++ -M -I/usr/X11R6/include" OPTS="-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DVIEWER_HAVE_DCMTK" TARGET=LINUX depend
```

What's wrong there?

Edit: I followed jw013's advice and installed csh. Now I get the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this Undefined variable problem?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but eww, a `csh` script?  It seems so ... primeval.

Comment: A `csh` script named `build.sh`?  Double eww.

Comment: You must have run it as `sh ./build.sh`.  If you had run it as `./build.sh`, you would have gotten a different error message.

Comment: i'm curious why you posted screenshots of your terminal rather than simply copying and pasting.

Comment: Text is always preferred over images, in regards to stdout/stderr.  Text can be indexed.

Answer (score 14):

The script is declared as

```
#!/bin/csh -f
```

The syntax also matches that of `csh`.  You are running it as

```
sh build.sh
```

Since `csh` is compatible with neither Bourne nor POSIX `sh`, the mismatch causes lots of syntax errors.  The correct way to run `build.sh` is either

```
csh build.sh
```

or by making it executable (`chmod +x build.sh`) and running it directly, letting the system choose the correct interpreter according to the shebang (`#!`) line:

```
./build.sh
```

(assuming it's in your current directory).

The `HOSTTYPE` variable is only defined in [tcsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh), which is one of the csh implementations. If `csh` is some other csh implementation on your machine, make sure that you install tcsh, and run

```
tcsh build.sh
```

or change the first line of the script to `#!/bin/tcsh -f`.

Comment: Thanks; I installed csh via apt-get, but got this:csh build.sh
HOSTTYPE: Undefined variable. Any ideas?

Comment: `HOSTTYPE` is automatically set by most shells.  I'm not sure why it is not set for you - maybe you could make a new question for this.  Post your shell version and relevant details about your environment.

Comment: @omgzor There are two implementations of csh: the [original C shell by Bill Joy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), and the more recent and more featureful [tcsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh). Only tcsh defines `HOSTTYPE` (​＠jw013: and bash, following tcsh). This script assumes that `/bin/csh` is the tcsh implementation.

Comment: The `#!/bin/csh -f` isn't in the snippet that the OP posted, but it is in the `build.sh` script for the app.  I was going to mention that `build.sh` is a poor name for a csh script, but that's the fault of the app developer, not of the original poster.